# How to replace existing data (key/value pair) instead of appending to an array via immutable js?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability

I have a web app built on `react/react-redux/redux saga/immutable js`. 
 From `reducer`, I have following lines of code.

```
const initialState = fromJS({ container: [] });
export default(state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SOME_ACTION.FOO: {
            return state.set('container', state.set('container').push(fromJS({ key: action.name, data: action.address })));
            }
```

From UI component I can add new entry as `name: Peter, address: somewhere` as `key/value` pair then `redux store` is properly updated. With given code, if I add same name and same address, it won't replace existing `value` based on `key` instead it keeps appending to the `container` array or List in immutable context.

I tried `state.update` to rectify the situation but that was not working out. What correct syntax I should use in order to replace existing `key/value` pair entry from `container` array?

[update]

Below code block did a trick for what I need.

```
return state.update('container', (container) => {
    const index = container.findIndex((x) => {
        return x.get('key') === `${action.name}`;
     });
     return index === -1 ? container.push(fromJS({ key: action.name, data: action.address })) : container;
```

Comment: The object must have a unique id or value in order to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It keeps appending to the `container` due to this code, as you always push the object to the array :

```
state.set('container').push(fromJS({ key: action.name, data: action.address }))
```

If you want your data to override then why not use a `{}` instead.

```
const initialState = fromJS({ container: {} });
export default(state = initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case SOME_ACTION.FOO: {
        let info = { ...state.get('container').toJS(),{ action.name:action.address } }
        return state.set('container', info);
```

`key` should be some `unique identifier` for eg: `user id`

Comment: I found a workaround solution but I believe this would work. Ty for your time and advice.